# Fonts not loading in internet explorer 11

Tags: css, express, fonts, xampp, internet-explorer-11

So I have these two fonts (well technically just one):

```
cachet-bold-webfont.ttf
cachet-bold-webfont.eot
```

In FF and Chrome they load up just fine.

[image]

But in IE, they won't load:

[image]

Here's my font face:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'cachet-bold';
src: url(../fonts/cachet-bold-webfont.eot); 
src: url(../fonts/cachet-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url(../fonts/cachet-bold-webfont.ttf)  format('truetype');
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now here is the weird part. In IE11, if I refresh with [F5], the fonts won't load and I get this error:

[image]

But, if I press ctrl + [F5], the site requests all of the assets and the fonts load and I don't get any errors.
Afterwards, if I press F5 again, the fonts disappear. Again, if I then press ctrl+F5, the fonts load again.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Thanks,

EDIT: I've narrowed it down a little more.
If I disabled my appcaching (with the manifest file), fonts load every time.

My manifest file has both fonts though:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v0.4.1 - 2016-03-31
# AppCache Auto Update: 1466554101434
CACHE:
fonts/cachet-bold-webfont.ttf
fonts/cachet-bold-webfont.eot
```

When I say "Appcaching", I'm referring to the Client side app caching api.

```
<html manifest="myproject.appcache.manifest">
```

Even after taking the manifest file away, loading the page, seeing the fonts load, and putting the manifest file back in. Suddenly the fonts stop loading yet again. But still remember, I can press ctrl+f5 at any time and the fonts load again.

Comment: Minus the part where disabling appcaching causes it to load. Is this what you do? Just go around reading 5% of questions and hoping to get upvotes by finding 20% similar "duplicates"?

Comment: there are no rep points for closing questions. just here to help.

Comment: if your question doesn't relate to IIS, what server are you using?

Comment: I get the same results when I host my files with XAMPP and NodeJS with express.